# Can I remove the highlight around braces, quotations etc.?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This highlight around certain coupled characters really, really bothers me.
I believe it was implemented in a recent update as I never noticed it before!

It normally causes me to lose my cursor and I end up typing out of the braces/quotations.

What I'm talking about are these little buggers:

[image]

[image]

If someone knows how to turn this off, that would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Liam

Comment: [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be94e8aw(v=vs.90).aspx) will help you too

Comment: Literally everyone who responded here actually did provide a solution so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: ...except I did provide a solution for you. You're even saying you agree with me that you didn't research enough. What is the problem here? I think you are being overly-sensitive. If you're going to ask more questions without researching them properly, you can expect not to be very well received here.

Comment: No worries man, best of luck to you.

Comment: @LiamT98 You shouldn't take downvotes to heart in any case. It merely represents an opinion of one user that the question isn't useful to others *in general*. Even so, it's still the opinion of a single person. In this situation, I would tend to agree - because the solution to this *is already on SO*, and so this question does not add anything beneficial to the site. The mentality `I'd rather continue developing rather than sweat over the small things` means you'd rather other people spend time fixing it, rather than you. That's not a good mentality to have in a community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Options, such as "Automatic delimiter highlighting" and "Brace Matching"

### [Options, Text Editor, General](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Text_Editor.General);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6)&rd=true)

> Automatic delimiter highlighting
>   When selected, delimiter characters that separate parameters or item-value pairs, as well as matching braces, are highlighted.

### [Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Environment.Fonts_And_Colors);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6)&rd=true)

(all sorts of details at that link)

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated @Chris Fannin

Comment: @LiamTaylor Glad I could help. :-)